# The metric space of binary sequences with the metric $\sum 2^{-k}|x_k-y_k|$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let's consider the following metric space $(X,d)$, where:

$X = \{ \ x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,.....,x_k,.....)\ |\ x_j \in \{0,1\}\ \forall j \geq 1\ \}$

$d(x,y) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}} | x_{k} - y_{k} |$

This is the space of all sequences consisting of $1$'s and $0$'s. This is a metric space, it's easy to see why.

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $x,y \in X$ satisfy $d(x,y) < \frac{1}{2^n}$. I'm trying to prove that this implies $x_{k}=y_{k}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$.

My attempt:

$d(x,y) < \frac{1}{2^n}\ \ \ \ \implies \ \ \ \ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}} | x_{k} - y_{k} | < \frac{1}{2^{n}}$

But $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}} = \frac{1}{2^{n}}$, so this implies:

$\implies \ \ \ \ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}} | x_{k} - y_{k} | < \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}}$

I get stuck here, can someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: If $x_k\neq y_k$ for some $k\leq n$, then $|x_k-y_k|=1$, and then $\frac{1}{2^k}\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^i}|x_i-y_i|<\frac{1}{2^n}$ is a contradiction

Comment: @That should be the answer as ... well, it is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Patricio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545157/result-about-a-certain-metric-space#comment3146461_1545157) proved the implication $d(x,y) < \frac{1}{2^n}\implies x_k=y_k\ \forall k\le n$ in a comment:

> If $x_k\neq y_k$ for some $k\leq n$, then $|x_k-y_k|=1$, and then $$\frac{1}{2^k}\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^i}|x_i-y_i|<\frac{1}{2^n}$$ is a contradiction